# Не отображаются стили страницы в webview при использовании Jsoup

Tags: java, webview, jsoup

Мне нужно было убрать лишние блоки со страницы

```
<div id="">..</div>,
```

решил это сделать через jsoup:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://site.ru").get();
```

но при отображении в webview не показываются стили (выводится текст,блоки без каких либо отступов и т.д)

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, doc.outerHtml(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Что -то делаю не так видимо, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ответ пришел неожиданно, указал в первом параметре метода LoadDataWithBaseURL ссылку на корень сайта

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://site.ru/page/page").get();
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://site.ru", doc.outerHtml(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

и стили стали отображаться нормально